# Writing to internal text files

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, text-files

I'm using Windows Forms in C# and I'm trying to have a method within my program where the user can update an internal text file. This text file is part of the program, but is not listed in resources. Currently my program can read the textfile into a textbox just fine, I'm just struggling with how to write to that file (and because the contents are temporarily in the textbox, it is fine if the text file contents are entirely overwritten with the contents of the textbox).

Here is the code I'm using to read into the textbox (there's probably a better way of doing this- but currently it works):

```
var resourceRegions = "SalesMap.Regions.txt";
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

using (Stream fileStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceRegions))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
{
    string Regions = "";

    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        Regions += reader.ReadLine();
        Regions += Environment.NewLine;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(Regions);
    textBoxEdit.Text = Regions;
}
```

And here is the code I'm trying to use to write to the textbox (on a button click):

```
var resourceRegions = "SalesMap.Regions.txt";
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

using (Stream fileStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceRegions))
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
{ 
    try
    {
        writer.Write(textBoxEdit.Text.ToString());
        writer.Close();
        writer.Dispose();
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Problem...");
    }
}
```

Currently it fails at `new StreamWriter(fileStream))` and throws "ArgumentException was unhandled". Anybody see what I'm missing? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiled resources, assembly contents are read-only.

If you want to provide a way for content to be updatable, first write out the resource to disk and then load and save from that location for use in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

It probably doesn't know the path to write it to but It might be easier to just write it out like this:

```
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\Salesmap.regions.txt", textboxedit.text);
```

This is the proper way to do it with streamwriter, just to give you some ideas:

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = 
        new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines2.txt"))
    {
        foreach (string line in lines)//lines is an array of strings
        {

               file.WriteLine(line);

        }
    }
```